# Google maps stopped working

Tags: jquery, google-maps

My map script is not working. I have two maps on two separate pages, they were working at first, but now that I've made some CSS changes (nothing to do with map) it is no longer displaying. When I inspect it in the browser, the container is still there but it just wont show up. Here it is on my testing server www.trutattoo.amdesigns.studio

Here is my script with my api key. I have it on both pages.

```
   Here it is on my html page

   <!-- ============ Google Map - START ============ -->

            <div id="map"></div>

            <!-- ============ Google Map - END ============ -->

    And this is the jquery

  function init() {

    // Google Map options
    // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions

var mapOptions = {
        draggable               : isMobile() ? false : true,
        streetViewControl       : false,
        disableDoubleClickZoom  : true,
        scrollwheel             : false,
        zoom                    : mapData.zoom,
        center                  : new google.maps.LatLng(33.009378,-96.842931),
        styles: [{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#444444"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.locality","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#cfc8be"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":45}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#cfc8be"},{"visibility":"on"}]}]
    },

    // Create the Google Map using the map container and options defined above
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position    : mapOptions.center:  {lat:-34.397, lgn: 150.644},
        map         : map,
        icon        : mapData.marker
    });
```

}

Comment: could be that you css  is broken before the css code for map..

Comment: Here is my css for the map #map {
    height: 500px;
}

.gmnoprint img {
    max-width: none;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position    : mapOptions.center:  {lat:-34.397, lgn: 150.644},
   map         : map,
   icon        : mapData.marker
});
```

to

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position    : mapOptions.center,
    map         : map,
    icon        : mapData.marker
});
```